# If the definite integral of $f(x)$ is equal to zero, $f(x)=0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $F(t) = \int^t_0 f(x)dx$ is the zero function, can we say $f(x)$ is the zero function?

Comment: You can take $\int_{0}^{2\pi} sinx dx$. Here $f(x)$ is $sinx$ which is not $0$ every time.

Comment: Is the equality true for every $t$ or just for some specific value of $t$?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that if $f(x)$ is continuous, it has to be the zero function. For non-continuous functions, one has to be more careful as 5xum's answer indicates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A Definite Integral Gives Algebraic Area under a curve in the given interval. The difference in Area and Algebraic Area is that Algebraic Area is Normal Area taken with sign,So it can be negative but Normal Area is always positive.So, If a function Has equal area below and above x-axis the algebraic area cancels each other but the Normal Area is added.Hence $$\int_0^tf(x)dx=0$$ does not imply $$f(x)=0$$.You can take $$sinx$$ as example.

Normal Area means the Area under the curve.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take for example

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x\neq 0\\ 1& x=0\end{cases}$$